# Application. Received Google message received: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising

Tags: google-play, admob, policy, ads

I have thé application on google play over 2 years this morning i received à mail from Google that tell me that application is deleted

I only use Google admob sdk i have no autorization on manifest file here is the mail i received from Google

Hi developers at ***** 2018,

After review, Listening Prep 2/3 – TOEIC® Test, com.toeic.***i.listening.part2, has been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.

Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app.

Next steps: Submit your app for another review

Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User Data policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and make appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect sensitive user information, be sure to abide by the above policies, and include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app. 
Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.

How can i résolve this problèm Please ?

Comment: did you got the solution?....i am lookout for solution having the same problem